# Angular material table - column width by string length

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

In my app I have a bunch of different material tables.
I want to find some way to automatically set column width.

I know, I can set this directly in CSS like this and I try this

```
.mat-column-position {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
}
.mat-column-name {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
.mat-column-weight {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
.mat-column-symbol {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
```

But in this way, I need to manually set the width for every table.

I also try dynamically set CSS with SCSS

```
@mixin mat-table-columns($columns)
{
    .mat-column-
    {
        @each $colName, $props in $columns {

            $width: map-get($props, 'width');

            &#{$colName} 
            {
                flex: $width;
                min-width: $width;

                @if map-has-key($props, 'color') 
                {
                    color: map-get($props, 'color');
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}

@include mat-table-columns((

    orderid: (width: 6rem, color: gray),
    date: (width: 9rem),
    items: (width: 20rem)

));
```

But in all of these ideas, I need to manually set the width.

I try to find, is there any way to automatically set the width relative to the string with the longest length

```
| abc   | abcdefg | abcdefgh |
| abcde | abc     | abc      |
| ab    | abcdef  | abc      |
```

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8kyrsp?file=src/app/table-flex-basic-example.css) for example. Thnx

Comment: You could add those styles into global style.css or style.scss

Comment: Sure, but still I need to set manually width

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using native table elements, this way your cells will auto resize and you should never have to worry about setting them manually.

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8kyrsp-gnhbfd?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-flex-basic-example.css

Answer (score 3):

As robbieAreBest suggested, the native table element will resize.
What I didn't know is that all that needs to be done is this:

```
<table mat-table>
    your table
</table>
```

instead of (old way)

```
<mat-table>
    your table
</mat-table>
```

See [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#:%7E:text=%3Ctable%20mat%2Dtable%20%5BdataSource%5D%3D%22myDataArray%22%3E%0A%20%20...%0A%3C/table%3E) for more info

Comment: Thats it! Even though the width 100% was being applied to the table(tested using border red), the content of the table wasnt being adjusted to take the whole empty space. Forcing mat-cell to X width was working in some weird way.